# Unit Step Function Finding slope

Tags: laplace-transform

[image]

How do i find the using $y=mx+c$ for the slope above
from $1$ to $3$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! Please explain what you have done so far and what your understanding of the problem is.

Comment: Do you want the slope or the Laplace transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The segment on the interval $[1,3]$ pass by the points $(1,2)$ and $(3,0)$ hence
$$m=\frac{0-2}{3-1}=-1$$
Now for $x=1$ we have
$$y=2=-1\times1+c\iff c=3$$